# For each element in list byref

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I have a list of structures that have to be passed as argument to threads; one for each element in the list. The thread will loop until a boolean in the structure become true.

So I made:

```
        For Each ScaleElement In Scales
            Dim NewThread As New System.Threading.Thread(Sub() ScaleThread(ScaleElement))
            NewThread.Start()
        Next
```

With ScaleElement passed byref. But then, I have a warning: "Wsing the iteration variable in a lambda expression may have unexpected results". And the warning it's right because it seems to run the thread on the same element.

If I try:

```
        For Each ScaleElement In Scales
            Dim NewScale = ScaleElement
            Dim NewThread As New System.Threading.Thread(Sub() ScaleThread(NewScale))
            NewThread.Start()
        Next
```

It works fine but, as the "NewScale" is a different element, when I try to set the condition for breaking the loop in the elements in the list, of course it doesn't work.

ScaleStruct:

```
Public Structure ScaleStruct
    Dim Key As String
    Public Scale
    Dim Database As String
    Dim Table As String
    Dim Field As String
    Dim Keyname As String
    Dim Interval As Integer
    Dim Insert As Boolean
    Dim Format As String
    Public Abort As Boolean
    Dim FailCount As Integer
End Structure
```

The scale variable is set (on the configuration file reading) to a class that reads the scale.

Scales is a "Public Scales As New List(Of ScaleStruct)" so, when I want to stop the threads, I would like to use a boolean (Abort) in the struct.

Then, the thread is a loop:

```
Private Sub ScaleThread(ByRef Tscale As ScaleStruct)
        Do Until Tscale.Abort
            ...
        Loop
End Sub
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that `ScaleElement` has a Boolean property to determine whether or not to keep going? If so, it sounds like the simplest approach would be to make it a class rather than a structure. (It *sounds* like it would be a better fit as a class anyway, to be honest.)

Comment: @Stefano: Well it's not clear what you're *doing* with the `ScaleElement` to indicate that the thread should stop, but if the code is how I imagine it to be, using a class should work, yes. The new thread will have a reference to the same object that the "controller" thread still has, so changes to the object from either side will be seen by the other. (You need to be careful around synchronization to make sure the changes are visible according to the memory model, but that's a different issue.)

Comment: I'll explain better editing the post, meanwhile I'll try changing the structure to a class.